# Make a new JS Object using an old one, see description for example

Tags: javascript, object

This one is pretty straight forward, I think I just don't know what tool to use. I've got an object which looks like this:

```
{
  email: "email@aol.com", phone: "222-333-4444"
}
```

i am looking to convert it to the following array with nested objects

```
[
 {
  name: "email", value: "email@aol.com"
 },
 {
  name: "phone", value: "222-333-4444"
 },
]
```

im familiar with .map() and Oject.keys, just keep running into a wall on this one.

this is what i've been trying but im getting syntax errors

```
const data = Object.keys(data).map(key => {name: key, value: data[key]});
```

can anyone help? hopefully some quick points for someone. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return object from arrow function, you must wrap it in `()` [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#advanced_syntax)

> To return an object literal expression requires parentheses around expression

```
const data = {
  email: "email@aol.com", phone: "222-333-4444"
};

const result = Object.keys(data).map(key => ({name: key, value: data[key]}));
```

Comment: agree except the solution conflates the result (`data`) with the input (`data`)

Comment: im giving him credit, helped me w the syntax. thanks!! and working after using unique props